# Why does this KVO code crash 100% of the time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

The code below will crash inside of `NSKVOUnionSetAndNotify` calling `CFDictionaryGetValue` with what appears to be a bogus dictionary.

It seems to be a race between the swizzled `addFoos` / `NSKVOUnionSetAndNotify` code and the act of adding and removing KVO observers.

```objective-c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TestObject : NSObject
@property (readonly) NSSet *foos;
@end

@implementation TestObject {
    NSMutableSet *_internalFoos;
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    BOOL observed;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    _internalFoos = [NSMutableSet set];
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    // Start a bunch of work hitting the unordered collection mutator
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            while (YES) {
                @autoreleasepool {
                    [self addFoos:[NSSet setWithObject:@(rand() % 100)]];
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Start work that will constantly observe and unobserve the unordered collection
    [self observe];
}

- (void)observe {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        observed = YES;
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foos" options:0 context:NULL];
    });
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (observed) {
            observed = NO;
            [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foos"];
            [self observe];
        }
    });
}

// Public unordered collection property
- (NSSet *)foos {
    __block NSSet *result;
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        result = [_internalFoos copy];
    });
    return result;
}

// KVO compliant mutators for unordered collection
- (void)addFoos:(NSSet *)objects {
    dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{
        [_internalFoos unionSet:objects];
    });
}

- (void)removeFoos:(NSSet *)objects {
    dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{
        [_internalFoos minusSet:objects];
    });
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        TestObject *t = [[TestObject alloc] init];
        [t start];
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10000, false);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it so surprising? You're adding and removing a key-value observer on one thread while mutating the observed property on another. So, you are likely to remove the observation internal records while they are being used.

Comment: Why are you using a concurrent queue at all?! Why aren't you using the context parameter for your KVO observation? Why aren't you calling dispatch_main in main? Why are you using dispatch_barrier_sync and not just a serial queue? Why are you accessing ivars directly instead of using accessors?

Comment: @KenThomases, thanks for the reply. It is kind of surprising to me. A class cannot be expected to control the thread upon which it is observed by a consumer.

Comment: @quellish, thanks for the reply. I often use a concurrent queue and dispatach_barrier to employ the reader/writer pattern. That is, I allow multiple concurrent readers, but writers are exclusive.

I am accessing the ivar directly because the public property is an NSSet and the ivar is NSMutableSet. I'm pretty sure that access to the ivar is thread safe because of the reader/writer pattern described above.

Comment: @Eric, a serial queue is more than adequate, and does not have many of the issues that using a barrier has. See the concurrency programming guide section on remove lock-based code for guidance. As far as direct ivar access, you can make the NSMutableSet private. You are using a concurrent queue, so no, even using a barrier it's not thread safe. Your "bogus" dictionary is exactly what will happen. You are also creating a potential deadlock.

Comment: @quellish, dispatch_barrier will allow only a single block to execute concurrently - even in a concurrent queue. You're right that the reader/writer pattern recommendation is to do the write with barrier_async, but in this KVO code, that would mutate the value AFTER didChangeValue gets called - which would be bad.

Comment: @Eric, you are using dispatch_barrier_sync, which can deadlock. You are using a concurrent queue, which will use however many different threads it wants, and has different guarantees about *execution* and *scheduling* than a serial queue. You are trying to force a concurrent queue to behave like a serial queue. Don't.

Comment: @Eric, "but in this KVO code, that would mutate the value AFTER didChangeValue gets called" , if you are concerned about didChangeValue:forKey: being called "before" your value is mutated, why aren't you controlling when it's called? This could be easily solved using recursive decomposition.

Answer (score 6):

The actual crash you get is an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when the key value observing dictionary is accesed. The stack trace is as follows:

```
* thread #2: tid = 0x1ade39, 0x00007fff92f8e097 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-priority', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff92f8e097 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8ffe2b11 CoreFoundation`CFDictionaryGetValue + 145
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8dc55750 Foundation`NSKVOUnionSetAndNotify + 147
  * frame #3: 0x0000000100000f85 TestApp`__19-[TestObject start]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=<unavailable>) + 165 at main.m:34
    frame #4: 0x000000010001832d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #5: 0x0000000100014925 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #6: 0x0000000100016c3d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 601
    frame #7: 0x00000001000182e6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
    frame #8: 0x00007fff9291eef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 314
    frame #9: 0x00007fff92921fb9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
```

If you set a symbolic breakpoint with the symbol `NSKVOUnionSetAndNotify` the debugger will stop where this method is being invoked.
The crash you are seeing is because automatic key-value notifications are being sent from one thread when you invoke your `[addFoos:]` method, but then the change dictionary is being accessed from another thread. This is stimulated by your use of the global dispatch queue when calling this method, as that will execute the block in many different threads.

#### There are mulitple ways to fix this crash, and I will try to walk you through this to give you a more thourough understanding of what is going on.

In the simplest case, you can fix the crash by using the key-value coding mutable proxy object for this key:

```
NSMutableSet *someSet = [self mutableSetValueForKey:@"foos"];
[someSet unionSet:[NSSet setWithObject:@(rand() % 100)]];
```

That will stop this particular crash. What's happening here? When `mutableSetValueForKey:` is called, the result is a proxy object that forwards messages to your KVC-compliant accessor methods for the key "foos". The author's object does not actually fully conform to the required pattern for a KVC compliant property of this type. If other KVC accessor methods are messaged for this key, they may go through non-thread safe accessors provided by Foundation, which can result in this crash all over again. We'll get to how to fix that in a moment.

The crash is being triggered by *automatic* KVO change notifications crossing threads. Automatic KVO notifications work by swizzling classes and methods at runtime. You can read a more in-depth explanation [here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html) and [here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-08-lets-build-key-value-coding.html). KVC accessor methods are essentially wrapped at runtime with KVO-supplied methods. This is in fact where the crash in the original application is happening. This is the KVO inserted code disassembled from Foundation:

```
int _NSKVOUnionSetAndNotify(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    r4 = object_getIndexedIvars(object_getClass(arg0));
    OSSpinLockLock(_NSKVONotifyingInfoPropertyKeysSpinLock);
    r6 = CFDictionaryGetValue(*(r4 + 0xc), arg1);
    OSSpinLockUnlock(_NSKVONotifyingInfoPropertyKeysSpinLock);
    var_0 = arg2;
    [arg0 willChangeValueForKey:r6 withSetMutation:0x1 usingObjects:STK-1];
    r0 = *r4;
    r0 = class_getInstanceMethod(r0, arg1);
    method_invoke(arg0, r0);
    var_0 = arg2;
    r0 = [arg0 didChangeValueForKey:r6 withSetMutation:0x1 usingObjects:STK-1];
    Pop();
    Pop();
    Pop();
    return r0;
}
```

As you can see, this is wrapping a KVC compliant accessor method with `willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` and `didChangeValueForKey: withSetMutation:usingObjects:`. These are the methods that send out KVO notifications. KVO will insert this wrapper at runtime if the object has opted into automatic key value observer notification. In between these calls you can see `class_getInstanceMethod`. This is getting a reference to the KVC compliant accessor being wrapped, and then calling it. In the case of the original code, this is being triggered from inside NSSet's `unionSet:`, which was happening across threads and causing the crash when it accessed the change dictionary.

Automatic notifications are sent by the thread where the change occured, and are intended to be received on the same thread. This being Teh IntarWebs, there is a lot of bad or misleading information out there about KVO. Not all objects and not all properties emit automatic KVO notifications, and in your classes you can control which do and don't. From the [Key Value Observing Programming Guide: Automatic Change Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW1) :

> NSObject provides a basic implementation of automatic key-value change notification. Automatic key-value change notification informs observers of changes made using key-value compliant accessors, as well as the key-value coding methods. Automatic notification is also supported by the collection proxy objects returned by, for example, mutableArrayValueForKey:

This may lead one to believe that all descendants of NSObject emit automatic notifications by default. This is not the case - may framework classes do not, or implement special behavior. Core Data is an example. From the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW15) :

> NSManagedObject disables automatic key-value observing (KVO) change notifications for modeled properties, and the primitive accessor methods do not invoke the access and change notification methods. For unmodeled properties, on OS X v10.4 Core Data also disables automatic KVO; on OS X v10.5 and later, Core Data adopts to NSObject’s behavior.

As a developer, you can ensure that automatic key value observer notifications are on or off for a particular property by implementing a method with the correct naming convention, `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversOf<Key>`. When this method returns NO, automatic key value notifications are not emitted for this property. When automatic change notifications are disabled KVO also does not have to swizzle the accessor method at runtime, as this is done primarily to support automatic change notifications. For example:

```
+ (BOOL) automaticallyNotifiesObserversOfFoos {
    return NO;
}
```

In a comment the author stated that the reason he was using `dispatch_barrier_sync` for his accessor methods is that if he did not, KVO notifications would arrive before changes occured. With automatic notifications disabled for a property, you still have the option of sending these notifications *manually*. This is done by using the methods `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`. Not only does this give you control of when these notifications are sent (if at all), but on *what thread*. Automatic change notifications, as you recall, are sent from and received on the thread where the change occured. 
For example, if you wanted change notifications to happen *only* on the main queue, you could do so using recursive decomposition:

```
- (void)addFoos:(NSSet *)objects {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foos"];
        dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^{
            [_internalFoos unionSet:objects];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foos"];
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The original class in the author's question was forcing KVO observation to start and stop on the main queue, which seems have been an attempt to emit notifications on the main queue. The above example demonstrates a solution that not only addresses that concern, but ensures that the KVO notifications are correctly sent before and after the data changes.

In the example above I modified the author's original method as an illustrative example - this class is still not correctly KVC compliant for the key "foos". To be Key-Value Observing compliant, an object must first be Key-Value Coding compliant. To address this, first create the [correct Key-value coding compliant accessors for an unordered mutable collection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) :

Immutable:
`countOfFoos`
`enumeratorOfFoos`
`memberOfFoos:`

Mutable:
`addFoosObject:`
`removeFoosObject:`

These are just the minimum, there are additional methods that can be implemented for performance or data integrity reasons.

The original application was using a concurrent queue and `dispatch_barrier_sync`. This was dangerous, for many reasons. The approach recommended by the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) is to instead use a serial queue. This ensures that only one thing can be touching the protected resource at a time, and it is from a consistent context. For example, two of the above methods would look like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)countOfFoos {
    __block NSUInteger  result  = 0;
    dispatch_sync([self serialQueue], ^{
        result = [[self internalFoos] count];
    });
    return result;
}

- (void) addFoosObject:(id)object {
    id addedObject = [object copy];
    dispatch_async([self serialQueue], ^{
        [[self internalFoos] addObject:addedObject];
    });
}
```

> ### Note that in this example and the next, I am not including manual KVO change notifications for brevity and clarity. If you want manual change notifications to be sent, that code should be added to these methods like what you saw in the previous example.

Unlike using `dispatch_barrier_sync` with a concurrent queue, this will not allow a deadlock.

[image: This is how you get deadlocks]

The WWDC 2011 Session 210 [Mastering Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#210) showed the correct use of the dispatch barrier API for implementing a reader/writer lock for a collection using a concurrent queue. This would be implemented like this:

```
- (id) memberOfFoos:(id)object {
    __block id  result  = nil;
    dispatch_sync([self concurrentQueue], ^{
        result = [[self internalFoos] member:object];
    });
    return result;
}

- (void) addFoosObject:(id)object {
    id addedObject = [object copy];
    dispatch_barrier_async([self concurrentQueue], ^{
        [[self internalFoos] addObject:addedObject];
    });
}
```

Note that the dispatch barrier is accessed asynchronously for the write operation, while the read operation uses `dispatch_sync`. The original application used `dispatch_barrier_sync` for both reads and writes, which the author stated was done to control when automatic change notifications were sent. Using manual change notifications would address that concern (again, not shown in this example for brevity and clarity).

There are still issues with the KVO implementation in the original. It does not use the `context` pointer to determine ownership of an observation. This is a recommended practice, and can use a pointer to `self` as a value. The value should have the same address as the objected used to add and remove the observer:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foos" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(void *)self];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == (__bridge void *)self){
        // check the key path, etc.
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

From the NSKeyValueObserving.h header:

> You should use -removeObserver:forKeyPath:context: instead of -removeObserver:forKeyPath: whenever possible because it allows you to more precisely specify your intent. When the same observer is registered for the same key path multiple times, but with different context pointers each time, -removeObserver:forKeyPath: has to guess at the context pointer when deciding what exactly to remove, and it can guess wrong.

If you are interested in a further understanding of applying and implementing Key Value Observing, I suggest the video [KVO Considered Awesome](https://vimeo.com/95999854)

### In summary:

• Implement the required [key-value coding accessor pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW5) (unordered mutable collection)

• Make those accessors thread safe (using a serial queue with `dispatch_sync`/`dispatch_async`, or a concurrent queue with `dispatch_sync`/`dispatch_barrier_async`)

• Decide wether you want automatic KVO notifications or not, implement `automaticallyNotifiesObserversOfFoos` accordingly

• Add manual change notifications appropriately to accessor methods

• Make sure that code which accesses your property does so through the correct KVC accessor methods (i.e. `mutableSetValueForKey:`)

Comment: This is full of voodoo. Using the `internalFoos` property has no practical difference from accessing the instance variable. The original `..._sync()` calls couldn't have caused deadlock because there was no chance that the code within them would block, especially not on the properties of this class. Using a concurrent queue with barriers for reader/writer locking is as safe as using a serial queue and is blessed by Apple (it's in one of the WWDC sessions). Serial queues are serviced by the concurrent queues, so you have no more control over the execution context with them.

Comment: "Using the internalFoos property has no practical difference from accessing the instance variable." If you would like, I can update the answer illustrating the difference. "Serial queues are serviced by the concurrent queues, so you have no more control over the execution context with them." Please point me to the libdispatch source that illustrates this.

Comment: "Using a concurrent queue with barriers for reader/writer locking is as safe as using a serial queue and is blessed by Apple (it's in one of the WWDC sessions)." If you are talking about the WWDC 2011 session 210, the recommendations are specific, and VERY different from this implementation. Perhaps you mean some other session?

Comment: A getter, especially a `nonatomic` one, is simply a method returning the instance variable. Putting a call to such a method in place of directly accessing the variable does nothing but use a few more cycles. WWDC 2011 session 210 is one place where Apple says that the barrier functions can be used for reader/writer locking, yes. It's not at all different from this case. It's a general technique whenever you want to allow multiple simultaneous readers but only one writer at a time.

Comment: The source for the serial queues feeding into concurrent queues is https://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.92.1/src/queue.c. `dispatch_queue_create()` calls `dispatch_queue_create_with_target()` with a `NULL` target queue, for both serial or private concurrent queues. So, that function picks a target queue. The only difference between the two types is whether the target queue is an overcommit queue or not. That controls how [`pthread_workqueue_attr_setovercommit_np()`](http://people.freebsd.org/~sson/thrworkq/pthread_workqueue.3.txt) is called.

Comment: Also, in that same file, notice the implementation of `dispatch_get_global_queue()`. It uses the same exact `_dispatch_get_root_queue()` function as `dispatch_queue_create_with_target()` does to get the target queue for a serial queue.

Comment: Your statement "Serial queues are serviced by the concurrent queues" seems to be the opposite of your later statement "the serial queues feeding into concurrent queues". Care to ellaborate?

Comment: "WWDC 2011 session 210 is one place where Apple says that the barrier functions can be used for reader/writer locking, yes. It's not at all different from this case." Err, what? There are some important differences. http://imgur.com/BjYBwhM

Comment: "The only difference between the two types is whether the target queue is an overcommit queue or not.". The width of the queues is different. A concurrent queue has a width set to UINT32_MAX. The overcommit flag tells the work queue wether it can start new threads.

Comment: "A getter, especially a nonatomic one, is simply a method returning the instance variable. Putting a call to such a method in place of directly accessing the variable does nothing but use a few more cycles. " That is an implementation detail that you should not depend on, does not apply to setters, and may not be valid at all when using KVO or other Apple frameworks.

Comment: "serviced by" and "feeding into" mean the same thing. Don't know why you think they're in conflict. The only difference between the two types of **target** queues into which serial or concurrent queues feed is the overcommit flag. The overcommit flag on controls whether threads are created when the system is saturated. Both types can create threads. If you think this reader/writer locking scenario is different from the one that Apple was describing, then it's incumbent on you to explain why.

Comment: Regarding the getter, you are the one asserting that calling one is semantically different than accessing the instance variable. The ambiguity in implementation contradicts your argument, not mine. If a getter **could** be identical to direct instance variable access, then your assertion that using it changes something is baseless.

Comment: The use of `_sync()` in the write side of the reader/writer lock doesn't change anything about its correctness. It affects the submitter of the block, not how the block itself executes.